# C# - Select multiple buttons at run time and save values to database at once

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

i'm developing airline seat map application. But i can't change multiple buttons values at once.

I searched my solution, but not found as i want.

My sequence are

1. Select i want blocked seats
2. Buttons are highlighted when selected
3. I will add "Save" button. This button save all selected buttons value to Database.
4. That's all

Here's my dynamic buttons code:

```
     private void GenerateSeats()
    {
        const int seatSpacing = 6;
        const int middleRowWidth = 50;
        const int seatWidth = 40;
        const int seatHeight = 30;
        char[] Seatletter = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
        //panel1.Width = 6 * (seatHeight + seatSpacing) + seatSpacing + middleRowWidth;
        //panel1.Width = 1200;

        var buttonSize = new Size(seatWidth, seatHeight);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 155; i++)
        {
            int SeatRow = i / 6;
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                int thisRow = i / 6;
                int thisColumn = j % 6;

                int seatTop = thisRow * (seatHeight + seatSpacing);
                int seatLeft = thisColumn * (seatWidth + seatSpacing);

                string SeatCode = (SeatRow + 1).ToString() + Seatletter[j];

                if (thisColumn >= 3) seatLeft += middleRowWidth;

                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Passengers where seat = @checkseat", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkseat", SeatCode);
                SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                Button SButton = new Button();
                SButton.Click += new EventHandler(SButton_Click);
                SButton.Size = buttonSize;
                SButton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                SButton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
                SButton.Text = SeatCode;
                SButton.Location = new Point(seatTop, seatLeft);
                SeatMapPanel.Controls.Add(SButton);

                if (Reader.Read()) //Check seats (available or not)
                    {
                        SButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.CXV_blk_j;      //already reserved seats                      
                    }
                else 
                    {
                        SButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.CXV_def_j;    //Available seats
                    }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And result:

[image: I've created these buttons dynamically]

Comment: Your code is not very efficient - you execute 156 SQL statements when you could just get all allocated seats in a single call. Creating 156 buttons is also not terribly efficient - you could just render the whole thing as a single bitmap and then detect mouse clicks on it. Your question is also unclear - what's not working?

Comment: Now i want generate seats with blocked seats. Blocked seats are restricted to reservation. Specified user will select blocked seats and these seats are not available for reservation. So i want select seats to block. and save them to database at once.

Comment: can you suggest better idea on SQL statement and creating buttons to be more efficient.

Comment: In a single query get all the seats which are booked. You can does this in a separate function. Then while  generating the panel set the buttons back ground

Comment: @Ramankingdom Thank you for solution. I'll try.
We have 3 status for seats.
1. Available seat 
2. Already assigned seat - Not Available 
3. Blocked seat - Not available (Restricted)

Blocked seats set by specified role user. How i select blocked seats by one action. Like select seats should be blocked click over button and finally get all values and save to DB.

Comment: if you can use wpf you will save your time

Comment: This code looks inefficient. it's better to send one sql command instead of send a command for each seat. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This way you can arrange your code and logic
```

1. Get All The Available Seats
2. Get All the Assigned Seats
3. Get All the Not Available Seats
4. Get All the Blocked Seats

The above 4 functions will give you the information for e.g seat no which is Available can be

For e.g

```
 List<int> GetAllTheAvailableSeats() //You can return anything which is suitable
   {
       //your logic of database
   }
```

similarly, you can write other methods.

Now once the data is available for each of the seat statuses you can generate the seat panel. Here you should not add modify buttons in the code. Omit all the code other than generation for e.g

```
 private void GenerateSeats()
{
    const int seatSpacing = 6;
    const int middleRowWidth = 50;
    const int seatWidth = 40;
    const int seatHeight = 30;
    char[] Seatletter = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
    //panel1.Width = 6 * (seatHeight + seatSpacing) + seatSpacing + middleRowWidth;
    //panel1.Width = 1200;

    var buttonSize = new Size(seatWidth, seatHeight);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 155; i++)
    {
        int SeatRow = i / 6;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            int thisRow = i / 6;
            int thisColumn = j % 6;

            int seatTop = thisRow * (seatHeight + seatSpacing);
            int seatLeft = thisColumn * (seatWidth + seatSpacing);

            string SeatCode = (SeatRow + 1).ToString() + Seatletter[j];

            if (thisColumn >= 3) seatLeft += middleRowWidth;

            Button SButton = new Button();
            SButton.Click += new EventHandler(SButton_Click);
            SButton.Size = buttonSize;
            SButton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            SButton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            SButton.Text = SeatCode;
            SButton.Location = new Point(seatTop, seatLeft);
            SeatMapPanel.Controls.Add(SButton);

        }
    }
}
```

After the seat generation is done you can set their status for e.g

```
public void SetSeatStatuses() 
{
   foreach(var seatinfo in AvailableSeats) //available seat  can be int or anything
    {
      var button =  SeatMapPanel.Controls[seatInfo] as Button;
      //set background images here
    }
}
```

Similaryly, for other statuses.

**Note: - Optimization as per your need**